# How to get the first row of every data record using perl?

Tags: perl

Data Record looks like this:

```
  1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  __Data__
  1bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  __Data__
  1ccccccccccccccc
  cccccccccccccccc
  cccccccccccccccc
```

Perl code:

```
 $/="__Data__";

 open READFILE,"<","a_test.txt" or die "Unable to open file $file";
 while(<READFILE>)
 {      
    if(/^([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n/sm)
    {       
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
close(READFILE);
```

This code only outputs `1aaaaaaaaaaaa` and not the other first line of the other records. I'm sure there are other ways of doing this but using this code format, how can I get the other records to display only their first line. The ideal results would be:

```
 1aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
 1bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 1cccccccccccccc
```

Comment: Works as expected, just by changing regex. $\ is ok as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line:

```
$ perl -nle 'print; $_=<> until /^__Data__/ or eof' input.txt
```

Comment: Not idiomatic solution but showing profound knowledge of command line.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your regex to output desired content,

```
if (/ (.+) /x) { print "$1\n"; }
```

in each record this will match first line as you described above.

Comment: can anyone tell me why my code is not working? It seem as if it should

Comment: `.` doesn't match `\n` by default, so it's very similar to your first capture.

Comment: @user1937198 it wont, just first line as there is no /s modifier.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's tempting to process the file section-by-section, in this case it seems more clear-cut to go line-by-line -- because the desired output is line-oriented. This avoids the need to parse the sections.

```
my $marker = "__Data__\n";
my $flag   = 1;

while (my $line = <>){
    print $line if $flag;
    $flag = $line eq $marker;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remove leading withespace, split in newline character and print first element, like:

```
while(<READFILE>)
{           
    s/\A\s*//;
    printf qq|%s\n|, (split /\n/)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will repeat an idea that I've said many times here: A line is only *one* implementation of the record concept. It is the default implementation, but it is not the only one.

- Set the *record separator* to `"\n__Data__\n"`
- Simply print all the non-newline characters pulled from a regex:

  ```
  use English qw<$RS>;
  local $RS = "\n__Data__\n";

  while ( <> ) { # A generic read
      print /(.*)/, "\n";
  }
  ```

Thus, you split the data up by records, delimited by `__Data__` and pull out only the first line.